# Calculating Linear and angular speed of a Robot using Bosch Radar Sensor's radial velocity component

Tags: localization, velocity, sensors, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to obtain linear and angular speed of the robot relative to a world frame using a Bosch radar sensor.

The radar sensor provides the information of 32 objects which it can detect at a time, the information contains the location of the object and radial velocity of the object.

If the objects are stationary and the robot is moving towards the object with 1 m/sec. than the radar will show the radial velocity of the object -1 m/sec.

Now the problem is that I am not able to calculate the angular speed of the robot because the data is to sparse. and if I get the linear speed and angular speed of the robot in Radar frame, than how should I transform this information to a stationary world frame

Comment: How  "radar frame" is defined? In think if you are able to retrieve angular speeds (as different from radial speeds) of objects in you radar the absolute value does not change because "World frame" is stationary. If robot as an extra angular speed with respect to the world frame (a rotation around a point that is not the centre of the robot: the robot is moving on a circle) you need to subtract it from the relieved value. (Hypotesis: all angular speed are around vertical axis and radar gives always true "absolute" values).

Comment: radar measures the objects in surrounding reference to its own frame. I have to measure the speed and angular speed of the robot based on the information radar provides. as the robot is moving therefore I need the information in a stationary world frame.